How to make a clean install of Blender 4.2?
I recently updated Blender from 4.1.1 to 4.2.0. During the installation I selected "Load 4.1.1 Settings." I then learned it's recommended to start with a clean install of 4.2.0 rather than install previous settings, so I uninstalled 4.2.0, rebooted my Windows 11 PC, and then installed Blender 4.2.0 again, but this time the installer added the 4.1.1 settings by default, i.e., it never gave me the option to opt out of the 4.1.1 settings.
How do make a clean install of Blender 4.2.0? Does File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings accomplish the same thing? Thanks.

Blender doesn't "install" in the same way other programs do. It's a portable file with it's own dependencies and executable you just unpack into a folder wherever. Your addons and config are stored in C:\Users\jmobl\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\{4.x}. If you delete the folder for whatever version you're using in the AppData folder then it will basically be a factory reset.

Your user preferences are stored at %appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.2\(you can paste that in the address bar of file explorer or run menu( Win  +  R ) to quickly get there. It might be a good idea to make a backup of that before deleting or after you set everything up the way you like it. You could also reset all the settings directly from Blender from File -> Defaults menu:

You would need to go to Preferences(Edit -> Preferences) and hit Save Preferences to make that permanent:


Thank you for the responses! I uninstalled Blender 4.2 again, and deleted the 4.2 folder, but when I reinstalled 4.2, it again did not give me the option to load 4.1.1 settings, and it appeared to have loaded some 4.1.1 settings anyway, so I went to File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings and saved those preferences. I'm going to assume this is enough of a clean start. Thanks again!
